# Is it advisable to write to a plist from a UITableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, plist

I have a UITableView and am wondering if it's advisable to write to a plist file after a user selects a row in a table. Basically the user selects a row (or many) and then touches an APPLY button and the plist would be updated recording which rows have been selected by the user.

thanks for any help or advice

Comment: Its your decision to choose the way of persisting selection,plist can be used. But can you let me know how you are going to use this plist file and why not a simple dictionary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. **Yes, You can do this.**
2. I don't think there's any problem with this.
3. However, make sure you don't overwrite it. As in clear it first and write it. Or, it might cause a conflict in your logic.

Comment: Also, consider storing more than just the section and row values that were selected, in case the underlying data changes.